# Can I use a Carbon Copy Cloner with a source disk that's larger than the target disk?

Tags: applications, hard-drive, backup

[Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) is a great utility that's saved me a few times over the years. I've always used a much larger target drive than the source so I've never run into this problem before.

Now I have a 1 TB source and a 750 GB target drive. Only ~300 GB of the source drive is actually used?

Will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - CCC copies by file and so will manage.

This was my original setup and worked. It is now more complex as I now have more data on the source than can fit on the target, I manage this by choosing the files in CCC and deselecting ~/Downloads /tmp etc.

Comment: Just confirming that this did indeed work as described.